# Where do I find Oil?

Tags: starbound

In Starbound, there are many new things introduced into the game in the Nightly builds (for the upcoming Winter update). One of which is many changes to progression...

I'm up to a part where you're meant of craft Steel. Except Steel is not crafted from a Metalworking Station (made of 1 Iron + 1 Coal). Instead, it is made from an alloy furnace using 3 Oil + 1 Iron.

---

Iron is plentiful for me; I can find them easily by digging further down into the surface of a planet. But I've haven't come across any signs of oil.

**Question:** Where does oil commonly spawn?
*Is there a minimum planet treat "level" (not a number) or is it tied to specific biomes? Or what?*

Comment: I've found out where they spawn. But I'm not spilling the beans (posting the answer) until somebody finds out themselves (a shot at some reputation).

Comment: So is this just in the unstable builds at the moment?  I haven't played in a while but I gather the stable build hasn't been updated since March.

Comment: Yes, @Krjax, It's all only in the unstable nightly builds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oil can be found under the surface, in caverns of **Desert planets**.

References:

1. The wiki: http://starbound.gamepedia.com/Oil
2. This picture:
   [image: The dark water is oil.]

The dark water seen in this picture is not  water found in the underground tar biome (stable builds). They inflict a debuff when walked into and can be mined with a liquid-upgraded Matter Manipulator.

Comment: Some underground biome also have oil instead of water, but since you wouldn't know until you dig down, better just go desert for oil.

Answer (score 0):

It can not only be found in caves but there are also small to huge lakes of oil on the surface (tar biomes).

Comment: Do you have a picture? And are you talking about the stable builds or the nightly builds? **And I hope this answer isn't a comment.**

Comment: They do appear on the surface, but I'm pretty sure that's the over-burned or frozen ocean planets.. (Either one of them) | And the tar biome doesn't exist anymore.. Not that I could find it.

Comment: I just landed on a desert planet and there was a tar biome that contained oil. It doesn't seem to appear on all desert planets though so you may have to visit a few to find some.

Answer (score -5):

I Found some oil in tar biomes but I couldn't find any underground...